# Joomla get article content of subcategory in a module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

How can I include article data from database of a subcategory? I have successfully got the subcategory using `JCategories` API helper, however I have not yet found a way to get the article in the subcategory below is my module helper file:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.application.categories');
class Modtopviewcourses extends JCategories
{ 
     public static function getdata($catid)
    {
         $categories = JCategories::getInstance('Content');
          $cat = $categories->get($catid);
          $children = $cat->getChildren();
          $res=array();
          $res['articles']=$children;
          return $res;
     }
}
```

Comment: What values are you getting in `$categories, $cat, $chidren` ?

Comment: Have you looked at the category and categories modules? They are extremely flexible about this kind of hting. If anything you could clone one of them to get what you want and save yourself some time.